# How could I extract the all of strings with @hotmail.com,

Tags: php

How could I extract the all of strings with @hotmail.com,at the end. If the txt file's name is foo.txt

```
a@a.com jhgvhdhf bahau@gmail.com hdghfd G@g.com dxf@hotmail.com
sdfvdgfh
ghb@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Fine, I haven't done my good deed for the day:

Best of luck. Technically email addresses *can* contain spaces, provided they're quoted. I do believe hotmail doesn't allow that, so you should be able to use this:

```
preg_match_all(/[^\s]+@hotmail\.com/, $string, $matches);
//replace $string with file_get_contents('path/to/foo.txt')
```

On your snippet, `$matches` then looks like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'dxf@hotmail.com',
    1 => 'ghb@hotmail.com',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Answering questions like this one only encourages help vampires.

Comment: @GordonM: Fair enough. Didn't realize that this was, in fact a re-post of the previous question the OP asked...

Answer (score -1):

Try this code to read file and parse:

```
if (($file = @file_get_contents('foo.txt'))
    && preg_match_all('/[^\s]+@hotmail.com/', $file, $matches)
) {
    $result = $matches[0];
}
```

So $result will store:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "dxf@hotmail.com"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "ghb@hotmail.com"
}
```

Comment: Don't suppress errors or warnings willy-nilly. They're there for a reason

Comment: Answering questions like this one only encourages help vampires